Moving media from downloaded Apple Photos library into Synology Photos with a minimal metadata loss
Problem:
I have an almost 2TB Apple Photos library already downloaded onto an external drive. I wanted to migrate this library into Synology Photos without re-downloading it from the internet. Exporting originals from Apple Photos was too time-consuming and impractical. After some investigation, I discovered that the .photoslibrary file is essentially a regular folder containing an SQLite database and the original images and videos. So, I moved this file to my Synology NAS.
Expected Outcome:
I wanted to move the media files from the .photoslibrary/originals directory into home/Photos on my NAS, organized in a %Y/%m/%d directory hierarchy. Ideally I would like to keep as much as possible metadata from Apple Photos.
Solution:
I created a program that:

Recursively loops through all files inside the originals directory.
Queries a CSV file (exported from the ZASSET table in the Apple Photos SQLite database). The CSV contains two columns: ZFILENAME and ZDATECREATED.
Converts ZDATECREATED into %Y/%m/%d format and creates/selects the appropriate folder inside home/Photos.
Moves the file into that directory.

Shortcomings:
A significant number of files in the originals directory have _2, _3 suffixes before the extension, and the database does not have ZASSET records for these files. How should I handle these?
In general, I'd like to hear suggestions from anyone who has done a similar migration of their Apple Photos library to Synology Photos. What is the best method with the least metadata loss?
Thanks!


Exporting originals from Apple Photos was too time-consuming and impractical - can you clarify why this approach didn't work? This would be the recommended approach


However to answer your question, have you looked to see if you can find these files in Photos itself?

First - I've no idea what a ZASSET record is, BUT have you considered using ExifTool to assist with this undertaking?

Could the _2, _3 suffixed entries be for edits or draft edits of photos and assets?

Technical details about the structure of the Photo's database have been gathered at https://github.com/RhetTbull/osxphotos/wiki

Welcome to the osxphotos wiki! The purpose of this wiki is to provide additional details on the implementation of osxphotos for developers who want to understand how the code works. It also documents details about the structure of the Photos database files for those that would like to extend osxphotos or create other projects that use the Photos database.

